# Applying for an UK Ancestry Visa, can't select that visa type on Teleperformance website

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I am applying for a UK Ancestry visa from South Africa, to live and work in the UK. I have completed my application form, signed the declaration, booked an appointment and paid the visa fees.

I now have to create a Teleperformance account in South Africa, before I can go to my appointment. When creating my Teleperformance account, the compulsory 'Visa type & Travel Purpose' dropdown only has the following options:

Student;
Transit;
Other Non-Settlement;
Family Visitor (>6 months);
Family Visitor (<6 months);
Settlement;
Visitor (>6 months);
Visitor (<6 months);
Tier 1;
Tier 2;
Tier 4;
Tier 5.

Ancestry Visa does not fall under any of those visa types. But I have to select one of these to move forward and create a Teleperformance account. Their Contact Us page is useless and is a 'Feedback and Complaints' page, where you can't actually add any feedback or complaints. There is no email or number to call, so I am stuck.

My visa appointment is very soon so I am stressing out a bit. If anyone has had experience with Ancestry Visas and this Teleperformance site, advice would be most helpful.

Comment: The Ancestry Visa is a type of Settlement Visa.  So you would select 'Settlement'

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. As a South African/Kiwi (I applied on my NZ passport), I too was eligible for an Ancestry Visa, and as it's not a temporary visa, but you're not settling, you'd select 'other non-settlement'.

Evidence:

- Settlement is "indefinite leave to remain" (source: [UK GOV](https://www.gov.uk/settle-in-the-uk))
- Ancestry gives you 5 years in the UK (source: [UK GOV](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/overview))
- you can however apply to extend, OR apply for settlement ([same source](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/overview))